# use Type at DynamoDB Output

Tags: typescript, amazon-dynamodb

I want to use a type with `DynamoDB` like this.

```
interface Custom {
  id: string,
  token: string,
}

const { Item }:GetItemOutput & { Item: Custom } = await DYNAMO_DB.get(params).promise();
```

My IDE spits this alert.

> Type 'PromiseResult' is not assignable to type 'GetItemOutput & { Item: Custom; }'.
>     Type 'PromiseResult' is not assignable to type '{ Item: Custom; }'.
>       Types of property 'Item' are incompatible.
>         Type 'AttributeMap' is missing the following properties from type 'Custom': id, tokents(2322)

How can I use typescript with Dynamodb?

Answer (score 2):

The actual object type you are receiving is `PromiseResult`, so the following will work

```
const result:PromiseResult = await DYNAMO_DB.get(params).promise();
```

but you don't gain great benefit so I would keep it to

```
const result = await DYNAMO_DB.get(params).promise();
```

using TypeScript doesn't mean you have to use types everywhere

Comment: From what I understand from the question, he is asking how to type the result data so typescript can pick up the data structure.

Answer (score 2):

I think it work for you

```
interface Custom {
  id: string,
  token: string,
  [key: string]: AttributeValue | string
}

const {Item} = await DYNAMO_DB.get(params).promise();
const ItemWithCustomType = (Item as Custom);
ItemWithCustomType.id
```

Comment: Very good, it would be nice if you documented the code a bit.